# Can the tag suggestion help-text be changed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

At present the tag suggestion help-text is (note the **11.04**):

> *at least one tag such as (11.04 networking command-line), max 5 tags*

> [image]

This is problematic for two reasons:

- it encourages people to add the version of Ubuntu they are using even though it might not be relevant
- it needs to be updated regularly because 11.04 is EOL and it is stupid to suggest a tag for a question that is not going to be answered.

Any suggestions for a better help-text?

Comment: The only way around this is to remove those tags.

Comment: No that's not true. We can simply ask for a standard help-text as here on meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply ask SO for a standard help-text as we have here on meta.

Comment: Ok I'll pat myself on the back and accept my own answer :) Nice idea, don.joey, but it will never happen.

Answer (score 4):

The list of tags shown in your screenshot is generated from the popular tags available in the database. It doesn't get manually updated.

Comment: I am not sure this makes sense in our case. Maybe we should ask SO staff look to into it?

Comment: On the meta site the list of tags is not based on popular tags of the db.

Comment: This question isn't about meta.

Comment: No but if it is possible on meta, it surely is possible on main.